# verify enabled protocols on HTTPS for POODLE vulnerabilty CVE-2014-3566

Tags: ssl, security

after recent [POODLE vulnerability](https://access.redhat.com/articles/1232123) I am going around and checking all my servers are configured correctly.

Configuration is usually easy, almost all services have a way to set which protocols are enabled.

However, I can't find how to verify that the connection can't be downgraded to SSL and the actual list of supported protocols that the server will offer and will accept.

I tried with fiddler but just say it's https, I tried in chrome connecting and it say TLS, but browsers automatically select the best available option.

Is there a way to initiate a connection and test either which protocol are supported or if SSL protocol can be used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
openssl s_client -connect <server>:<port> -ssl3
```

If the connection succeeds, sslv3 is enabled. 
If it fails, it is disabled. When it fails you should see something like:

```
error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure
```